# Rails custom Validations - model layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I am building a custom validation for one of our models that validates the format of a date. so that the dates should be `dd/mm/yyyy` currently it works with dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy. but we find that some people are entering ddmmyyyy and then rails eats that up and spits out something else.

So i made a custom validation

```
class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors[:transaction_date] << "Date must be in the following format: mm/dd/yyyy" unless /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.match(record.transaction_date)
  end
end
```

Then within the model that i want to validate the `transaction_date` i create a private model like this

```
def date_is_correct_format
  validates_with DateFormatValidator
end
```

And then call `validate :date_is_correct_format`

I have done this before but this time this doesn't seem to be working, and no exceptions are raised at all. I could even within the private method do this.

```
def date_is_correct_format
  this_is_a_fake_method_that_should_blow_up
  validates_with DateFormatValidator
end
```

and it runs the validations and passes everything fine. any idea as to what i am missing? i have been readinig the [Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_with) but i cant see anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the code you posted above, and it worked well.

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :date_is_correct_format

    def date_is_correct_format
      validates_with DateFormatValidator
    end
  end

  class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
      record.errors[:transaction_date] << "Date must be in the following format: mm/dd/yyyy" unless /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.match(record.transaction_date)
    end
  end
```

Then i try in console, the output is:

```
  [1] pry(main)> User.create!(:transaction_date=>'fdsf')
     (0.1ms)  begin transaction
     (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Transaction date Date must be in the following       format: mm/dd/yyyy
  from /Users/zuozuo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/activerecord-    4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
```

So what version of Rails do you use ?

or you can try:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_with ::DateFormatValidator
  end
```

this implement also works.

Comment: i am running rails 3.2.12. i know hey i thought it would work to. i am running it on an unicorn server with sidekiq workers. but i restart them each time i try

Comment: `validates_with ::DateFormatValidator` does that need the `::`

Comment: The `::` is not required.